# two identical machines act differently during OSD

Tags: deployment, sccm-2012

I use System Configuration Manager 2012, SP1 to PXE -> Windows PE -> OSD
Several computers

I got a Lenovo T520 in the door yesterday and wanted to OSD it
but in the task sequence step, I couldn't select a harddrive, (the machine has a working vista installation on it)

I have seen this problem before, usually that means the boot image doesn't have correct storage drivers, but For Lenovo T520, I had already applied the storage driver.

I hooked up another Lenovo T520, and its able to get past the step just like expected

What on earth could be the cause I can OSD 1 T520 laptop
and not another one? .. they are the exact same model

Answer (score 0):

Check the SATA mode in the BIOS.  It should be set to AHCI.  I don't know about Lenovos but I've seen Dells where the BIOS had the SATA mode set to RAID.  Also, I've seen where Intel Rapid Start/Rapid Storage or Intel Fast Boot features can also mess with it.  It's best to disable those features.